# Distinguish between 2 instances of admin-ajax.php

Tags: ajax, uploads, media-library

I've added an avatar image selector to my `profile.php` page.

I'd like to be able to alter the query that loads the image library using `pre_get_posts` but I can't find any way to distinguish between this page and the regular media library (`upload.php`).

Using the global `$pagenow` returns `admin-ajax.php` in both situations. Is there any other way to tell which page is loading the media library?

Comment: it is not clear what exactly are you asking, please edit the question and try to be more specific, the relevant parts of the actual code will help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much point to distinguishing `admin-ajax.php` since it's essentially same file with same logic running for many many purposes.

You are passing `action` data and hooking into respective action. So `action` is your identifier. If you are reusing same action and need to further differentiate — just pass more data with your GET/POST request and check for it in your handler.